# usewithtor: command not found

Tags: linux

I wish to use tor on the command line in conjunction with wget, ssh, etc.

The documentation that I have seen regarding this recommends installing the tor package (`apt install tor` / `yum install tor`) and then running the relevant program prepended with `usewithtor` eg.

```
usewithtor wget example.com/index.html
```

Having tried this on both debian and rhel distros I get

```
usewithtor: command not found..
```

Has this commmand now been deprecated?

Any help / guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`usewithtor` is deprecated, you want to use `torsocks` in it's place.

Previously there were various incarnations, the commands were kept for backwards compatibility but `torsocks` is what `torify`/`usewithtor` have just been a wrapper around for some time now.